# Troubleshooting WIFI - no access points listed

Tags: networking, wifi, wicd

I have a desktop computer which I run mostly with a wired network connection. When I start the Wicd network manager it says "No wireless networks found." Also, the command *iwlist* gives the same result:

```
# iwlist scan
eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     No scan results

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

I have installed the driver for my network card *firmware-b43-installer* and I know that Wi-Fi has worked previously. My router is located nearby and several other wireless devices are connected to it. Any clues?

Edit:

The output of *rfkill* indicates that Wi-Fi is enabled:

```
# rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Edit 2:

Here is some information about the wireless network card:

```
$ lspci -nn | grep Network
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4328] (rev 05)

$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4328] (rev 05)
        Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:0090]
        Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
```

Comment: are you sure that wifi on your machine is enabled. sometimes there is a button some where that needs to be pushed.

Comment: @ljaz I have a Mac Mini and I'm not aware of any such button. Is there a way to tell if Wi-Fi s enabled?

Comment: use `rfkill`. You might need to install it.

Comment: @RalphRönnquist I have added the output of `rfkill list` and if I'm not mistaken it says that Wi-Fi is enabled.

Comment: the output of `lspci -nn | grep Network` and your Linux dist

Comment: @GAD3R I run Debian 8.4 and the output of `lspci -nn | grep Network` is `03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4328] (rev 05)`

Comment: and `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` ?

Comment: @GAD3R I have added the output to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The command `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` will give you the information about the `Kernel driver in use`.
 According to [debian_wl](https://wiki.debian.org/wl) , you need to use `wl` module

Edit `sources.list` :

```
apt edit-sources
```

choose `nano` and add 'non-free sources' :

```
# Debian 8 "Jessie"
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

Update package:

```
aptitude update
```

We need to install `broadcom-sta-dkms` and `linux-headers`

Insert the cd-rom and type:

```
apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
```

Unload conflicting modules:

```
modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
```

Load the right module `wl`:

```
modprobe wl
```

Next step you need to unistall `network-manager` Or `wicd`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, today it just works (like before) and I haven't done any changes (no broadcom-sta-dkms or linux-headers installed). I wonder what went wrong previously.